# AngularJS ng-options create range

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a select element that has a list of numbers 1 to pages where pages is a variable that is the number of pages I have. What i don't know how to do is to structure the ng-options expression so that it will give me the numbers I need. Here is what I have so far

```
<select ng-model="page" ng-options="???"></select>
```

what do I need to put in the ng-options expression in order for it to create my select like

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    ...
    <option value="35">35</option>
</select>
```

do I need to create a function that returns an array of numbers and use it in there somehow or is there an easier way to do this?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

After posting my question i figured out one way to do it by creating a function called Range in my controller that takes two numbers and returns an array with all the values in that range.

```
$scope.Range = function(start, end) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        result.push(i);
    }
    return result;
};
```

then in the HTML I did

```
<select ng-name="page" ng-options="page for page in Range(1, pages)"></select>
```

Is this the simplest way to do this or is there a better way?

Comment: This is a clever parlor trick, but why not just use an HTML input of type number? You can even specify a range.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Your way works fine. Another option that came to my head is to use a filter, so you don't have to pollute your controller with Range.

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, min, max) {
    min = parseInt(min); //Make string input int
    max = parseInt(max);
    for (var i=min; i<max; i++)
      input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="page" ng-options="n for n in [] | range:1:30"></select>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/N3ZVp/1/

P.S. in your example in your main post, you didn't put `var` in front of `i`. So `i` is declared as a global variable in your example.

Comment: This is nice but how do I use the filter in the ng-options? I have about 1300 pages so I can't just list them all out and I need to be able to jump to any page so using a select element is my only real option. Fixed the undeclared variable in my for stmt.

Comment: I tried that in jsfiddle and it doesn't work. [http://jsfiddle.net/J4AYh/](http://jsfiddle.net/J4AYh/). **Edit:** However I was able to get it to work on my page. Could you make a working example on jsfiddle?

Comment: I dunno why that's not working.  I guess your Range function is the best.

Comment: Well your filter method worked on my site, I just couldn't get it to work in jsfiddle which I though was odd. I haven't used jsfiddle much so I wasn't sure if it was just me doing something wrong or not. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I wrote a nice version in CoffeeScript: https://gist.github.com/Dorian/311c7563fe6af6563d6f

Comment: The range in your jsfiddle example is inclusive (i<=max vs. i<max), which makes more sense to me.  Should the code in this answer be changed to match?

Answer (score 14):

Another solution to keep it all in your template:

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(10) track by $index+1">{{$index+1}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Using `[].constructor` instead of fancy "range" makers is neat.

Comment: @iMad this is returning a single option which is NaN
how to fix this, I am using angular 5

Answer (score 8):

Please add ng-model, like below

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="n for n in [] | range:1:30"></select>
```

After this your example will work in jsfiddle

Answer (score 7):

another approach without a for loop is this:

controller:

```
 $scope.arr = [];
 $scope.arr.length = count;
```

view binding:

```
 ng-options="arr.indexof(i) for i in arr"
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this only works if you want to start at 0.

Comment: you can always do "arr.indexof(i)+1 for i in arr"

Answer (score 7):

Andy's solution is great, however the range cannot go backwards. Here's the improved version:

```
/* 
 * Creates a range
 * Usage example: <option ng-repeat="y in [] | range:1998:1900">{{y}}</option>
 */
myApp.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, start, end) {    
    start = parseInt(start);
    end = parseInt(end);
    var direction = (start <= end) ? 1 : -1;
    while (start != end) {
        input.push(start);
        start += direction;
    }
    return input;
  };
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: See my edit of this below which will the last value of the range

Answer (score 5):

Piggybacking on martynas' answer.  I modified it to include the last value in the range:

```
/*
 * Creates a range
 * Usage example: <option ng-repeat="y in [] | range:1998:1900">{{y}}</option>
 */

.filter('range', function () {
    return function (input, start, end) {
        var direction;

        start = parseInt(start);
        end = parseInt(end);

        if (start === end) { return [start]; }

        direction = (start <= end) ? 1 : -1;

        while (start != end) {
            input.push(start);

            if (direction < 0 && start === end + 1) {
                input.push(end);
            }

            if (direction > 0 && start === end - 1) {
                input.push(end);
            }

            start += direction;
        }

        return input;
    };
});
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but returns empty array if start=end. Add the following after the parseInts to fix: `if(start===end) return [start];`

Answer (score 0):

In CoffeeScript:

```
app.filter 'range', ->
  (input, min, max) ->
    input.push(i) for i in [parseInt(min)..parseInt(max)]
```

And the HTML:

```
<select ng-options="n for n in [] | range:1:30"></select>
```

Here is the [gist with the Javascript](https://gist.github.com/Dorian/311c7563fe6af6563d6f)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a placeholder in select, then use below given solution. You need to first define the filter [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11161353/1230188).

```
<select>
    <option value="">-- Birth Year --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="n in [] | range:1900:2000">{{n}}</option>
</select>
```