# Angularjs, how use ng-repeat range 5 to 10

Tags: angularjs, loops, numbers, range, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use like this to loop number:

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="n in [] | range:10" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
</select>
```

This works, but how i can get like this with ng-reapet (5 to 10)?

```
<select>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="n in [] | range:6" value="{{$index+5}}">{{$index+5}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This throws an error in console. Unknown provider: rangeFilterProvider

Comment: @YasinKilicdere: You need to create the range filter. Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges Though, I don't think it scales very well.

Comment: @ParaphiliacOstrich: Thanks for the hint. Then the accepted answer is not correct, right?