# Complex JSON Array & addition of values

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Yo everyone.

I've got a **.json** file structured like that :

```
var var1 =
[ { "a":"soluce1",
    "b": 
           [ { "user1" : "username1",
               "ba" : "1" },
             { "user2" : "username2",
               "ba" : "2" } ],
    "c":"useless"
} ];
```

, my **.html** file :

```
<tr ng-repeat="varhtml in var1">
    <td>{{varhtml.b[0].ba}}</td>
</tr>
```

and it appears :

```
1
```

I know that all is good at first. For the next step, I would display

```
3
```

, result of (`1+2` : (`ba+ba` and more arrays if needed...)). At first glance I thought that was not really difficult but I don't know what I need to do with `<td>{{varhtml.b[0].ba}}</td>` or others files to have this wish.

Thank you in advance for the helps.

**WORKING RESULT** :

```
$scope.additionNumber = function (varhtml) {    
var total = 0;  
  angular.forEach (varhtml.b, function (ligne) {        
     total += ligne.ba;     
  });   
return total; 
}


<tr ng-repeat="varhtml in var1">
    <td><span ng-bind="additionNumber(varhtml)"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not precalculate the value and set that on the scope?

Don't entirely understand your question but if you want a sum of all the values then you could precalculate the value, or if it needs to be dynamic, calculate it with a method?

```
$scope.calculateValue = function() {
    // loop through array and add up the values
    // then return the value
    return value;
};

<span ng-bind="calculateValue()"></span>
```

If you just need to xn + xn+1 then you could use a [for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878038/1138620) and loop through b and do some logic?