# Is there a way to loop through a template in angular without using a collection?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a loop that prints HTML a certain number of times.  I know the number because its in the scope.  Must I loop through the numbers and push them into an array beforehand in order to use ng-repeat which seems to only accept collections?

Comment: You want to avoid the loop or the array creation ??

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to create an extra loop by building an array for ng-repeat to loop through.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges

Comment: ngRepeat is basically a directive. If you tend to use your functionality many times in the project, you may consider creating the directive with intended functionality as yours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to ng-repeat defined number of times instead of repeating over array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array)