# Create div dynamically on option select in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create `div`s dynamically using option select value but `ng-repeat` not working. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Following is my HTML code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Select Example - AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select id="shiftnumbers"
            ng-model="event.shiftnumber"
            ng-options="timeslot.value as timeslot.name for timeslot in shiftnumbers"
            ng-init="event.shiftnumber = shiftnumbers[0].value"
            class="btn">
    </select>
    <div ng-repeat="event.shiftnumber">{{event.shiftnumber}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my `Script` -

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){

    $scope.shiftnumbers = [];
    for(var i=0; i< 23; i++) {
        $scope.shiftnumbers.push({name: i, value: i});
    }
});
```

PLNKR LINK  - http://plnkr.co/edit/UruYYbXrTgxqXadIb8A3?p=preview

Comment: Take a look at this question [AngularJS For Loop with Numbers & Ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges)

Comment: @GruffBunny Thx for the link..I applied the range method here..but feel what satpal suggested fitted in my case too closely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new array *selectedShiftnumbers* to store selected values. Then use *ngRepeat* to list it.

*HTML*

```
<select id="shiftnumbers"
        ng-model="event.shiftnumber"
        ng-change="addShiftNumber(event.shiftnumber)"
        ng-options="timeslot.value as timeslot.name for timeslot in shiftnumbers"
        ng-init="event.shiftnumber = shiftnumbers[0].value"
        class="btn">
</select>
<div ng-repeat="shiftnumber in selectedShiftnumbers">
  {{shiftnumber}}
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$scope.addShiftNumber = function(num){
  $scope.selectedShiftnumbers = [];
  for(var i=0; i< num; i++) {
    $scope.selectedShiftnumbers.push(i);
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1YevD9Oau9VTzRBme0SH?p=preview)

Comment: but they are not creating that number of divs..that means if I select 10 then it must create 10 divs not a single div with number 10

Comment: @Trialcoder, Updated answer just slightly modified `addShiftNumber` function