# Execution of the loop 'x' times in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a loop that executes ten times:

```
ng-repeat="y in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]"
```

Can you do it in a nicer way?

Comment: This should help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14695228/4759033)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS For Loop with Numbers & Ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can try this:

```
 ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number)"
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.number = 5;
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
  return new Array(num);   
}
```

This will allow you the freedom to pass in any range.