# ng-pattern not working for form validation

Tags: angularjs, regex, forms

I have tried to use a lot of regex which I found on the internet but with no luck. I am trying to validate if a form's input ranges between 0-100 (both 0 & 100 are valid inputs) but for some reason The error is not showing up. Pasting my code below

```
<form class="row" name="myForm">
    <div ng-repeat="month in plan.months" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">{{month.label}}  : </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text"
           name="name"
           ng-model="month.value"
           class="form-control"
           ng-pattern="/^([1-9]?[0-9])$/"
        />
        <br />
    </div>
<span class="error" style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.name.$error.pattern">Please enter a Percentage value between 1 & 100</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not just use input[number] with a min/max? The example on this page covers your exact scenario. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges

Comment: Work but doesn't allowed 0 before: `ng-pattern="/^(100|[1-9]?[0-9])$/"`
Tell me if you want to allowed 0
Here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/oy14oxu2/33/

Comment: @israGab your fiddle is working great but when I integrate it with my code it is not working ;(

Comment: @MatthewGreen already tried that, no luck

Comment: @Vijay: you should have another issue. Do you have a javascript error in the console?

Comment: What do you mean by 'no luck'? The example in the doc does in fact work and would cover your situation. How does it not cover the case you need? That might shed more light on why you are having this issue.

Comment: @IsraGab nope no errors in the console.

Comment: @MatthewGreen i tried using the exact same code but just changing the input type to number, but still the validation error is not showing up when I enter a number beyond the rgeex exprssion.

Comment: @Vijay, instead of _{{month.label}} _ try {{myForm.name.$error.pattern}} and tell me what is the value.
like here: http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/oy14oxu2/35/

Comment: @IsraGab It is displaying false instead of the label names

Comment: Ok. Now write 799 in the input. (false should change to true)

Comment: @IsraGab nope does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@anurag -- the Solution you provided worked for numbers above 100 but was failing for below 0 numbers
& @andrew -- The same with your solution, was not throwing a validation error unless I enter -100 (ng-maxlength = 3) is working but that is not how we need it.

The original issue was with my Regex, finally the code that worked for me is

```
<form class="row" name="myForm">
    <div class="col-sm-2">{{month.label}}  : </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="number"
               name="percent_monthly_targets"
               ng-model="month.value"
               class="form-control"
               ng-pattern="/^[0-9][0-9]?$|^100$/"
            />
     <br />
        <span class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="myForm.percent_monthly_targets.$error.pattern">Please enter a Percentage value between 1 &amp; 100</span>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<form class="row" name="myForm">
    <div ng-repeat="month in plan.months" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2">{{month.label}}  : </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text"
           name="name"
           ng-model="month.value"
           class="form-control"
           ng-pattern="/^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0])$/"
        />
        <br />
    </div>
<span class="error" style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.name.$error.pattern">Please enter a Percentage value between 1 & 100</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also refer [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

Comment: No luck with this ;(

Answer (score 0):

It's because you cannot use a regular form with ng-repeat because of multiple inputs with the same name. Use ng-form inside ng-repeat to get isolated forms.

Also if you want numbers, just use input type=number with min and max values instead of using ng-pattern.

See working example https://jsfiddle.net/asimgeker/yjmoLtvv/

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="month in months" class="form-group">
      <ng-form name="myForm">
        <div class="col-sm-2">{{month.label}} : </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="myName" ng-model="month.value" class="form-control" />
          <br />
        </div>
        <div style="color: red" ng-show="myForm.myName.$error.max">Should be less than 101</div>
        <div style="color: red" ng-show="myForm.myName.$error.min">Should be greater than -1</div>
      </ng-form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not technically right that you must use `ng-form`, but this answer is on the right track.  The problem is that multiple inputs of your form have the same name.

Comment: @anurag you were right about the form being inside ng-repeat , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using a text input rather than a number input?

If not, try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/kqupg84y/

```
<form class="row" name="myForm">
        <div class="col-sm-2">{{month.label}}  : </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="number"
           name="name"
           ng-model="month.value"
           class="form-control"
           min="0"
           max="100"
        />
        <br />
    </div>
  <span class="error" style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.name.$error.pattern">Please enter a Percentage value between 1 &amp; 100</span>
  {{myForm.$error}}
```

(i removed ng-repeat for simplicity of fiddle)

That doesn't answer your question about using an ng-pattern though.

That being said, your regex may just be a bit off. rather than

```
/^([1-9]?[0-9])$/
```

you could try:

```
/^[0-9]+$/
```

if you're trying to match any number between 0 and 100.
Your regex looks like it's trying to match any number that is between 1 and 9, potentially followed by any other number... but if you're trying to make it inclusive of 0 and 100, i'm not sure it works as expected.

The tool I generally use for checking my regular expressions is:

http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that multiple inputs in your form have the same name.  You need to add some uniqueness to the input names.  A quick and dirty way to make form element names unique is to bind the name property to an expression that uses the `$index` of the `ng-repeat` like `name="month{{$index}}`.  Then you can use Javascript's [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the correct form element from the form controller:

```
<div ng-repeat="month in plan.months" class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">{{month.label}}  : </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="text"
          name="month{{$index}}"
          ng-model="month.value"
          class="form-control"
          ng-pattern="/^[1-9]?[0-9]$|^100$/"
       />
       <br />        
    </div>
    <span class="error" style="color:red" 
          ng-show="myForm['month' + {{$index}}].$error.pattern">
          Please enter a Percentage value between 1 & 100
    </span>
</div>
```

Here's [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jgCv1ECzkLbNtoaHRxLC) demonstrating this in action.  As an aside, your pattern incorrectly failed the string `"100"`, so I added an alternative to the regex.