# Ng-repeat without array for option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option selected>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

Says I have 3 qty in my json, I know can using loop using jquery but how do I build my html using ng-repeat of angular? since it doesn't have [1,2,3] but just 3.

http://jsfiddle.net/qpLuw80j/ Added jsfiddle to example my case clearer.

Comment: You should use ng-options it's specially made for select

Comment: @BrianOgden not sure it's a duplicate.

Comment: @CodyJonas You can always create your array in the controller.

Comment: @BrianOgden I have value of 3, how can I build 3 option element? it's not duplicate, pls reopen thanks!

Comment: @Lulylulu I have something like this [{qty:4},{qty:2}], so you're saying I should build another array?

Comment: @CodyJonas could you explain a little more please ? you have your array `[{qty:2}, {qty:4}]` and you wish having a select for each `qty` with the number of options from `1` to `qty` value ?

Comment: @Lulylulu http://jsfiddle.net/qpLuw80j/

Comment: it's not really clear what you are wanting to achieve.  Are you saying that `qty` is the *max* value, and you want to list every integer between `1` and `qty`?

Comment: @Claies yes, how to do it?

Comment: Try this out? http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/52z79dkz/1/

Comment: @CodyJonas just updated with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/qpLuw80j/2/

Comment: for select element I would have thought ng-select makes more sense than ng-repeat.

Comment: @CodyJonas please mark my answer as correct if helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `map` to add an array to each item of your initial array:

```
 $scope.myJson.map(function(item) {
    item.qtyArray = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= item.qty; i++) {
      item.qtyArray.push(i);
    }
    return item;
  })
```

and then

```
<select ng-options="item for item in json.qtyArray" ng-model="selected"> </select>
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/enf3uwr9/1/).

Answer (score 0):

put your ng-repeat inside the option tag
    option ng-repeat="value in values"

{{value.name}}

/option

then remove the rest of your option

Comment: <select>
        <option ng-repeat="json in myJson">{{json.name}}</option>

Comment: No, then it will be just 2.

Comment: you only have 2 objects in your array. you need to add more to have more items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **filter**:

check your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/qpLuw80j/2/

Filter defined as:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);

    for (var i=1; i<=total; i++) {
      input.push(i);
    }

    return input;
  };
});
```

With the repeat used like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:100">
  do something
</div>
```

## Your **Code**:

### HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    <div ng-repeat="json in myJson">
        <li>{{json.name}}</li>
        <select>
        <option ng-repeat="n in [] | range:json.qty" ng-bind="n"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

### JS:

```
var  angular = angular.module('app',['QuickList']);
angular.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);

    for (var i=1; i<=total; i++) {
      input.push(i);
    }

    return input;
  };
});
angular.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.myJson = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "banana",
    "price": 12,
    "qty": 3,
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "watermelon",
    "price": 12.9,
    "qty": 4,
  }
]

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a function on your fiddle to create a range for your quantity:

```
$scope.range = function(min, max, step) {
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) {
        input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
};
```

I got the range function from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17124017/1015690

Then, I used this function on ng-repeat for your options:

```
<option ng-repeat="n in range(1,json.qty)">{{n}}</option>
```

...and here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qpLuw80j/1/

:D