# Use of "for...of" in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ecmascript-6

Looking through ng-repeats source, it doesn't look like theres any instance of it using [for-of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Is there any custom directive that does this or some other way of achieving this loop in templates to make use of iterator functions?

**Class with iterator**

```
class Cache{

  constructor(items){
    this.cache = {
      "one" : 1,
      "two" : 2
    };
  };

  // custom iterator that turns our cache into an array
  // for use in "for...of" loops
  [Symbol.iterator](){
    var index = 0;
    // turn cache object into array of its values (underscore method)
    var data = _.values(this.cache);

    return {
      next: function(){
        if(index < data.length){
          return {
            value: data[index++],
            done: false
          };
        }else{
          return { done:true };
        }
      }
    };
  };

};

var myCache = new Cache();
// looping my cache in simple js would look like
for(let val of myCache){
  console.log(val);
}
// 1, 2
```

*proposed angularjs ng-repeat directive*

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in myCache track by $index"></li>
</ul>
```

However that does not work as ng-repeat does not implement `for...of`. My question is: is there a way to get the ng-repeat directive to work nicely with iterators with *minimal interface changes*, or better yet, a custom directive identical to ng-repeat that is made for `for...of` loops?

Comment: This may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges

Comment: ng-repeat's syntax is `object in array` or `(key, value) in object`. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: updated with example

Comment: Have to agree with MuliYulzary, if you are just trying to iterate an object you don't need to create a custom iterator becase a) `ngRepeat` can already iterate objects and b) The ES2016 feature [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) provides this implementation already

Comment: Its not about changing my implementation. I know that (of course) there are tons of other ways I could structure my code that will work with ng-repeat. My question is more "if I wanted to use an iterator function with angular templates, could I? Is there a custom directive (other than ng-repeat) that allows this?"

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert your iterable source to an array, which `ngRepeat` will be able to iterate:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in Array.from(myCache) track by $index"></li>
</ul>
```

Ideally this would happen in your javascript directive/controller:

```
scope.myCache = Array.from(new Cache());
```

View:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in myCache track by $index"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, something like this or similar might be the closest thing to what I'm looking for without writing a custom repeat directive. I was really hoping for a less intrusive interface but I understand ng-repeat simply doesnt implement it.