# Nested loops in angular html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I am having a problem to use loop in angular.
    See below scenario.

JavaScript code:

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++) {
       id=i+j;
    }
}
```

How can I do the same in my angular html?

Comment: what do you mean by angular html ? what is you are trying to achieve, kindly explain the use case and problem/error you are facing. so we can try to help you

Answer (score 3):

You can use ng-repeat. Like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in [] | range:6">
    <label ng-repeat="y in [] | range:6">{{x * y}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Chinito..It is useful for me

Answer (score 0):

you can not use for loop in html but you can run loop using ng-repeat in html.This link may help you [AngularJS For Loop with Numbers & Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges)