# How to repeat row in table in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular1.6

Here my code useing in php

```
@for($i= 0; $i < 15; $i++)
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
@endfor
```

but I want write it with angular+HTML

I trying this but not work

```
<tr ng-repeat="rows in other_line">
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
```

In my controller

```
$scope.other_line =15;
```

please help me to resolve it. thanks

Comment: make `other_line` an array of 15 items. For example `$scope.other_line = new Array(15)`, `ng-repeat="rows in other_line track by $index"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS For Loop with Numbers & Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges)

Comment: Should be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

ng-repeat takes an array , you have provided a value `$scope.other_line =15;`.
Code inside ng-repeat runs array.length times

So your code should be like

```
$scope.other_line = [];
$scope.other_line.length = 15;

<div ng-repeat="rows in other_line">
  <td></td
</div>
```

When this will execute in browser then, it will run 15 times

```
<div ng-repeat="rows in other_line">
 <td></td
</div>
<div ng-repeat="rows in other_line">
 <td></td
</div>
<div ng-repeat="rows in other_line">
 <td></td
</div>
.
.
.
.
<div ng-repeat="rows in other_line">
 <td></td
</div>
```