# angularjs - how to populate html select element options based on primitive not model

Tags: select, angularjs

Basically, I have an input control element where you can enter the total number of apples you have and based on the number of apples I want to set the max number of mini-apple pies you can make (for every 1 apple you can make 1 mini-apple pie). The Angularjs documentation states to use ngOptions, but I just want to base it off a primitive (total number of apples) not a model.

So, if I have a totalApples value of 2, then I want to have 2 options generated (with one having the value of 1 and the other the value of 2)

My code so far is as follows:

HTML snippet:

```
<input ng-model="totalApples" />
<select ng-options="">
  <option value="1">1</option>  //what I would like to have is the options generated 
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

In my controller I set the scope:

```
 $scope.totalApples = 2;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're interested in the selected value you should really use the `ng-options` directive in combination with `ng-model`. Take a look at [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qb1TkHdYKD3JVGUFsCtH?p=preview).

Also, don't be confused with the option values you see when you inspect the option elements. Angular makes sure correct value is bound to your model.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, for your example and remarks. This is the approach I would like to use as it seems to be the most straight forward while still solving my problem in an Angularish way (though putting in a filter probably is recommended)

Answer (score 3):

You would want a custom function to handle the generation of options for you. AngularJS directives work with data, the rest is up to you. Your goal is to supply it.

In your controller

```
$scope.options = [];
$scope.generateOptions = function() {
  newOptions = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= $scope.totalApples; i++) {
    newOptions.push(i);
  }
  $scope.options = newOptions;
}
```

And in your HTML you can simply use repeater since you don't really require select directive for this simple scenario.

```
<input ng-model="totalApples" />
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
</select>
<button ng-click="generateOptions()">Generate options!</button>
```

Comment: Also here's an answer similar to yours using a filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160513/angularjs-ng-options-create-range/11161353#11161353

Comment: Thank you, RickCigarette, for the response and the link, Rastapopulous, using a filter. It was helpful