# While lower than value

Tags: angularjs

Say I have a variable `x` with a value of `7`, I need to echo out this html

```
<a href="#" data-page="{{y}}">{{y}}</a>
```

Where `y` is 1,2,3... until `y == x`. How do I do this in Angular?

Comment: seems like ng-repeat to me http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11161353/1207991) you can create a filter which does this for you:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">
    <a href="#" ng-repeat="y in range(1,7)" data-page="{{y}}">{{y}}</a>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function Main($scope){
  $scope.range = function(min, max){
    var input = [];
    for (var i=min; i<=max; i++) input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dzwp/)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a treat :), just changed it to `y in range(0,numberOfPages)` to match my final use case

Comment: Cheers Tom! Glad to be of help.