# Filter out dates with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm displaying a date and passing it to the date:'shortDate' filter.  Now I want to add another level of filter so that if the date is not between a certain range it just doesn't display at all.

Do I have to write a custom filter for that?

Comment: See [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11161353/2055998).

Comment: To not display at all, it may be better to show or hide an element. E.g. why not: `<span ng-show="theDate > startDate && theDate < endDate">{{myDate | date:'shortDate' }}</span>`?

Comment: Thanks, Josh.  Your suggest makes the most sense to me.