# Bootstrap Select options too much code

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, select

I'm working with Bootstrap 3.3.6 and wanted to use a selector to choose a certain quantity.
Problem is that I want the options to go all the way to 99, but I noticed the code is too repetitive making the entire code a bit too much ..

Right now I've got:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="sel1">select quantity: </label>
   <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
       <option>3</option>
       <option>4</option>
       <option>5</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Do I have to write `<option></option>` 99 times or is there perhaps an easier and faster way to do this? 
Perhaps with angularJS? if so, any ideas how?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-options create range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160513/angularjs-ng-options-create-range)

Comment: Sorry, had no idea since I wasn't sure Angular was an option.

Comment: No problem. Just mark the question as a duplicate, then both questions can be found together

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`<input type="range"/>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#range-state-(type=range)) too:

```html
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="99" value="22">
```

In view of the semantic I think this element is better instead of 99 `<option>` items.

Answer (score 0):

If you have acces to PHP you could do:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="sel1">select quantity: </label>
   <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
     <?php for($i=1; $i <= 99; $i++){ ?>
       <option><?php echo $i; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a loop:

```
var text = 0;
for (i = 0; i <100; i++) { 
    text += "<option>"+[i]+"</option><br />";
}
```