# how to write loop in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

```js
m=5;
for(var i=0;i<m;i++){ 
   document.write(i); 
}
```

how output *i* in Angular

it is not working

```js
$scope.B = [];
        angular.forEach([0, 1, 2, 3], function (value, index) {
            $scope.B.push(value);

        });
```

Comment: [Take a Look This Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: Please change your second code to a [mcve]

Comment: Same Question [LINK_1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160513/angularjs-ng-options-create-range/11161353#11161353) [Link_2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873570/angularjs-for-loop-with-numbers-ranges)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, the problem you have most be related to something else in your AngularJS application.. Check the console and add more info to the question.

In the loop are added the elements to the array `$scope.B` and showed in the view using `json` filter.

Code:

```js
angular
  .module('App', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.B = [];
    angular.forEach([0, 1, 2, 3], function (value, index) {
        $scope.B.push(value);
    });
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="DefaultController">
    {{ B | json }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the explanation? Code only answers aren't very helpful